# python subprocess communicate() method slow

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following code and the `communicate()` method is taking unusually long than expected (around 2 seconds) to return the output. I'm new to python and tried my best. Can anyone tell me what's going on ?! I'm thinking that I should be flushing `stdin` or `stdout` somewhere?

I'm invoking another program from this python script.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("megam_0.92")
command="./megam -quiet -predict ../training_modelcp -nc multitron ../dummyst.txt"

result={}
result=subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,universal_newlines=True,bufsize=0)
k=[]
print("1")
print(result)
print("9")
# sys.stdin.flush()
out=result.communicate()[0]
# result.stdout.flush()
# sys.stdout.flush()
print("2")
print(out)
print("3")
for j in out.split("\n"):
    k.append(j.split("\t",1)[0])
print(k)
print("4")
```

I get to see "9" on the output within milliseconds and it takes around 2 seconds there and again prints the rest in milliseconds

Comment: how long does the command take to complete when  you run it from the command line? communicate will wait for the command to complete. If you use `for line in iter(result.stdout.readline,""):print(line)`  do you see output?

Comment: Do you need `shell=True` for this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham When i run from the command line it runs in the order of milliseconds. Yes, I see the output in my code but the problem is its taking too long.

Comment: @EtanReisner The result was same when I didnt use shell=True too.

Comment: The shell comment wasn't a solution just a question. Don't use it if you don't need it. It just adds overhead.

Comment: Does `megam` try to read from standard input at all? Do you need to hit anything on the command line to get it to return/finish when you run it normally? Can you use `strace` to see what it is doing when run from python?

Comment: Does `bufsize=-1` make a difference?

Comment: unrelated: pass `cwd=megam_0.92` to `Popen` instead of `os.chdir()`.

Comment: Could you add `start = time.time()` before `Popen()` and `print(time.time() - start)` after `.communicate()` call? Repeat the same with `out = subprocess.check_output(command.split())`

Comment: `shell=True` is a possible security hole and should not be used unless needed, because one is using a shell command.  Is OS Windows or other?  Does deleting `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` help?

Comment: In my case `universal_newlines=True` makes whole call much slower. I've switched to custom output processing which works faster: `'\n'.join(out.splitlines())`